# Issue with using ROS stereo_image_proc with negative disparities

Tags: ros

I am running the stereo_image_proc package on Ubuntu 16.04 using ROS kinetic and am having a strange problem. I noticed that I get better range in my disparity map when using negative disparities. However the resulting point cloud seems incorrect for the points corresponding to these negative disparity values. The points "Z" value is negative while the X and Y values are fine. This makes it difficult to correctly visualize the 3D reconstructed scene because points corresponding to objects far away are not where they should be. It seems like ROS stereo_image_proc simply does not know how to correctly handle projecting a disparity map with negative disparities into the point cloud. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by negative disparities? I assume that this can not happen naturally if the cameras are oriented parallel. How do you create those?

Comment: With high resolution cameras operating at a distance, it is virtually impossible to have them positioned perfectly parallel. The cameras will always be either slightly angled toward each other or slightly angled away from each other.

Comment: Ok, got you. Actually, I never had such issues. Are your intrinsic and extrinsic calibrations correct and are these information included in the `camera_info` topic?